# VS Error E1696, developing with openGL at the first time

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Error message:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdafx.h"  Twitch  c:\Users\PC\source\repos\Twitch\Twitch\Engine\Engine.h  1**

where the code is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef TWITCH_ENGINE
#define TWITCH_ENGINE


#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Engine {
public:
    static int SCREEN_WIDTH;
    static int SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    bool Initialize(char* windowTitle);

    void Update();
    void Render();

private:
    static GLFWwindow* window;
};

#endif
```

and in Twitch.cpp:

```
#include "Engine.h"

int Engine::SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;
int Engine::SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;
GLFWwindow* Engine::window = NULL;

Engine::Engine() {

}

Engine::~Engine() {

}

bool Engine::Initialize(char* windowTitle) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        cout << "Error initalizing GLFW" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        cout << "Error creating window" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    //OpenGL Setup
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    int xPos = (mode->width - SCREEN_WIDTH) / 2;
    int yPos = (mode->height - SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2;

    glfwSetWindowPos(window, xPos, yPos);

    //GL setup
    //Viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -10, 10);
    glDepthRange(-10, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    //Alpha Blending
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    return true;
}

void Engine::Update() {
    glfwPollEvents();

}

void Engine::Render() {
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

}

The file already included in my main.cpp file. 
Any reasons for the problem and solutions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the precompiled header file `"stdafx.h"` only supposed to be included in the *source* (i.e. `.cpp`) files?

Comment: stdafx has nothing to do with opengl. That's a [precompiled header file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header)

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: to include it in the .cpp files only.

Comment: I just began to learn. What is the diffrence between opengl and glfw?

Comment: only in the main file (called "Twitch.cpp")

Comment: Change "GLFW\glfw3.h" to "GLFW/glfw3.h"  in #include.  Change project setting to "Not using precompiler".

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Thank you @seccpur!